# How do I dynamically add a random amount of images to a div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a empty div `<div id="step2"> </div>` and I have a php script which retrieves images from a user selected website.

I currently can get the src from each image of a web page and console log it like this:

```
 <img src=​"https:​/​/​ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/​news/​320/​cpsprodpb/​D869/​production/​_97710455_f98a9739-db4a-4b2b-b418-7f68c55a43b8.jpg" class=​"thumbnail">​

 <img src=​"https:​/​/​ichef.bbci.co.uk/​images/​ic/​720x405/​p05fcpb5.jpg" class=​"thumbnail">​
```

How would I add them into the div without needing to refresh the page?

P.s The div is set to `display: none`. When a user inputs a url and clicks a button that is when the script is run and I use `jquery slideToggle` to show the div.

Here is the javascript code so far:

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $('#step2Btn').on('click touch', function() {
                link = $('#link').val();
                if (link !== "") {
                    $.post("ajax/articleThumbnail.php", {
                        article: link
                    }, function(thumbnails) {
                        thumbnails = JSON.parse(thumbnails);
                        var imgs = $.map(thumbnails, function(el) { return el });
                        var step2 = $('#step2');
                        for (var i = 0, j = imgs.length; i < j; i++) {
                            var img = document.createElement('img');
                            img.src = imgs[i]; // img[i] refers to the current URL.
                            $(img).addClass("thumbnail");

                            console.log(img);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#step1').slideToggle(100);
                    $('#step2').slideToggle(100);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdxbaglZXWAhUqLsAKHbsIAiQQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FWindowOrWorkerGlobalScope%2FsetTimeout&usg=AFQjCNHg9oIRsuTHdYN84jQhpdvYSQFE8A)/[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the elements created by `document.createElement('img')` to the div.

`$('#step1').append(img)`